# Set back to product category in Woocommerce Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to set a back button on my product page (to the product category).
I cant manage to get the category and echo on the page.

I have tried to use this code and it doesn't work...

```
         $cats=get_the_category();
         foreach($cats as $cat){

             if($cat->category_parent == 0 && $cat->term_id != 1){
                 echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id ).'">Return</a></h2>';
             }
             break;
         }
```

The first problem I have whit this code is what I have no option to set the parent category for the product. (If you can help me how can is set it, it will be great).

Also even if I'm removing this If condition, I don't get any link.

Thanks!

Comment: Code looks fine, can you try moving "break" inside the IF condition, just below the echo statement...as looks like your loop is breaking after first iteration even if no category is output yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get_the_category()` is made for WordPress categories, but not for WooCommerce product categories, which is a custom taxonomy. Same thing for `get_category_link()`…

So you should use instead [**`wp_get_post_terms()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) with an additional optional argument that will allow you to get only parent product categories. For the link you will use [**`get_term_link()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) instead:

```
// Get parent product categories on single product pages
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'include_children' => false ) );

// Get the first main product category (not a child one)
$term = reset($terms);
$term_link =  get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ); // The link
echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.$term_link.'">Return</a></h2>';
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).

Tested and works.

Comment: Yes, it works. But some infos are missing for readers that are aware of the wordpress basics.
The code has to be into a function and this function has to be hooked to a woocommerce hook e.g. woocommerce_before_single_product based on where you want to have the link in the page source code (see plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php). Also the name of the category can be accessed by $term->name just in case someone would like to have this info in the link like me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your break statement is breaking the loop even when no condition is met so foreach is terminating even before we have our match. Try moving the break; statement into the if condition block like following:

```
     $cats = get_the_category();

     foreach($cats as $cat){

         if($cat->category_parent == 0 && $cat->term_id != 1){
             echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id ).'">Return</a></h2>';
             break; // this will stop the loop as soon as we have a match.
         }

     }
```